# How can I update a huge zip archive, deleting any removed files, from the command line?

Tags: command-line, zip

I am rsync'ing a a folder from one host to another. I am then zipping the mirrored folder so that it can be transferred to tape.

Now, when I zip the folder (bearing in mind that the folder is ~300GB) using the below script it keeps the files which have been deleted from the directory that I am zipping.

```
zip -ru /home/rsync/www.zip /home/rsync/www/
```

This is because I'm using the `-u` (update) flag, which won't remove missing files from the archive.

In rsync I use the flag `--delete`, which removes files which no longer exist on the remote server. Is there a similar way of doing this with a zip archive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any option to do that. Here is a simple script you could use as a basis for something more robust:

```
unzip -lqq archive | cut -c 31- |
while read -r line
do if [[ ! -f $line ]]
   then
      zip -d archive "$line"
   fi
done
```

Here's a one-liner version:

```
unzip -lqq archive | cut -c 31- | while read -r line; do if [[ ! -f $line ]]; then zip -d archive "$line"; fi; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the new `zip -FS` option:

> This mode synchronizes the archive with the  files  on  the  OS,
> only  replacing  files in the archive if the file time or size of the OS file is
> different, adding new files, and deleting entries from the archive  where  there
> is no matching file.